# Nginx: 2 servers on same root, different index. Server 2 getting 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx

I have two servers that have the same root but different indexes. The second server is a subdomain of the first server, so I want to serve all the same files except the only thing I want different is the index.

Everything works fine except for the second `location` part on the second server giving me 403 forbidden error on every page I visit, yet it works just fine on the first server.

If I go to `domain.com/foo/` then I get the 403 forbidden. If I go to `domain.com/foo/index.html`, then I don't get the 403 forbidden and get served the correct files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen       443 ssl;

    root C:\Users\Lansana\Documents\Github\foo;
    index index.html;

    server_name   domain.org;

    location ~ /.+ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen       443 ssl;

    root C:\Users\Lansana\Documents\Github\foo;
    index subdomain.html;

    server_name   subdomain.domain.org;

    location ~ /.+ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to add a second file for the index on my second server.

Replace:

```
index subdomain.html
```

with:

```
index subdomain.html index.html
```